# Adding profiles to a community

Tags: profile, community

I am trying to enable self registration for community users, however I cannot choose a profile to which I want to associate the user. The drop down is blank. What do I do add profiles to this list? May be a "Customer Community User" profile or something.

[image: No profiles available for self registration for a community]

I really tried googling but cannot find anything.

Answer (score 4):

Navigate to administration | members  in your community management console and all portal profiles you want this community to access.

Depending on the assignment you make profiles list appear